# Can I use UIAlertController like this? iOS Design Query

Tags: ios, ios8, uialertcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` where users can manage (or edit) a `Core Data` object: change dates, add labels, tick boxes etc.

2 of the properties in the Object require the user to select an option from a list.

As an example, think of a property called `CompassPoints` and they can select either North, East, South, West etc.

What is the best practice here? Is it ok to have a button which will open a `UIAlertController`, presenting the user with 4 options and have them choose one? Or should I be pushing a new `UIViewController` onto the stack, displaying a `UITableview` and ask the user to select one of the rows?

UIAlertController seems a useful way to capture this data but I'm not sure if it's considered bad practice to work this way.

How would users expect to select their preferred CompassPoint in an application?

Answer (score 0):

`UIAlertController` is enough if you support iOS 8+ (Since its only available from iOS 8).

Answer (score 0):

From UX point of view, it would be nice to have something like a `ViewController` with buttons in 4 different directions. The second best option would be a **dropdown**. And then of course, you can use a `TableView`. `AlertController` doesn't seem to be a nice choice. These are all strictly my personal opinion based on my understanding of UX so far. From a programmer point of view,you can choose either of these which make your code better.